# Showing Travis build status in GitHub repo

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I remember recently seeing the Travis build status of a pr or commit in GitHub browsing the repository (but can't find where). I'm not talking about the Travis build status images in `README.md` but an actual GitHub feature (green box with a friendly check mark).

While my commits build on Travis just fine I'd like to get the results displayed in GitHub (which they don't do right now). I'd like to know how to enable this.

*UPDATE*

Found an [example here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/1051/commits) - see the small green check mark saying "Travis-CI build passed"?

Comment: The tick marks next to the commits appear automatically once the integration is set up correctly. You don't need to configure anything else for them. (Just to clarify this 3 years later, as it doesn't seem to have been said)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I give you my example - https://github.com/simkimsia/UtilityBehaviors

I wrote this in my README.mdown

```
### Status
[![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/simkimsia/UtilityBehaviors.png)](https://travis-ci.org/simkimsia/UtilityBehaviors)
```

So the answer is

```
[![Build Status](your travis url for the repo here.png)](your travis url for the repo here)
```

**EDIT:**

I realized that you may mean turning on the Travis Service Hook.

If that is what you mean, go to your github repo > Settings > Service Hooks. Use Ctrl+F and search for Travis.

**EDIT2:**

Go to https://travis-ci.org/profile/{fill in your own usernam}/profile

Then copy the token and paste it inside the Travis Service Hook page in your Github Repo Settings section.

Type in your username in Travis as well.

Try the test send token button.

You should see payload successfully sent.

If this works, your github repo is now hooked up to your travis.

**EDIT3:**

The OP is asking about the travis build status for commits found in pull requests pages.

He assumed that the travis build status will appear anywhere as long as there is a commit.

My answer is that the assumption is not correct.

Comment: Not quite what I mean- hopefully question becomes clearer with update. Service hooks are enabled- otherwise I wouldn't get Travis build at all?

Comment: This should be automatically filled in for you provided your Service hook is correctly setup and you have made at least 1 push AFTER your Travis is hooked with your GitHub. Note that the commits made BEFORE your Travis is hooked with your GitHub will not have the green arrows even AFTER you have hooked with Travis. If your is public, can show us the url to your travis page?

Comment: my gihub repo, current tree: https://github.com/andig/volkszaehler.org/tree/travis my travis build status: https://travis-ci.org/andig/volkszaehler.org/builds Builds have been setup weeks ago, and build fine, yet I can't find the assuring green "you're ok" marks

Comment: They appear in the pull requests page. See here? https://github.com/volkszaehler/volkszaehler.org/pull/55

Comment: doh: so they don't appear in _my_ commits but only when I push back to master?

Comment: same case as your example. They appear in pull requests page too yes?

Comment: +1 for the excellent support, though not the result I was hoping for (showing build status in the commits)

Comment: You can use SVG if you don't want blurry PNG

Comment: I cannot find any "Service Hooks" in my settings, where exactly is this option?

Answer (score 179):

## Github Integration

1. Go to https://travis-ci.org/{username or org}/{repository}
2. Click the **Status Image** (a pop-up will appear)

[image]

3. Select a branch, then click the dropdown <kbd>Image URL ▼</kbd> and set it to <kbd>Markdown ▼</kbd>.

[image]

4. Copy Paste the code to your `README.md`
5. Git add, commit & push. Refresh Github and you'll see the image now.

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer

Comment: Short and sweet answer

Comment: What about the other options that are there in the dropdown? Where do we use them ?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - see the link in the question

Comment: This button is always green, even if it is still building (should be yellow then)

Comment: this is the best answer.

Answer (score 26):

For getting markup You should go to

https://travis-ci.org/{username}/{repository}

Push the button with "Build status images" title under Your username at the top right

After that You will get a popup with markups for different environments
Here is a screenshot with popup for my own repository

[image]

Comment: Does not answer the question. I was referring to the GitHub integration.

Comment: I was refering to github integration too

Answer (score 2):

To have the same result as [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810386/showing-travis-build-status-in-github-repo) your push/pull request must build.

**This picture means Pull Request didn't build successfully**

[image]

**This picture means Pull Request was build successfully**
[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. Once Travis is set up, PRs are handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome, I just created a chrome extension for show travis-ci build time and status change in github. It's conveninent to show travis build statug in github repo, if only the repo is launched with travis-ci.

You can install it from [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github%2Btravis-v2/ekkfhiophiaakmeppcnkblpbbjlnlnmh)
Or see more details on [my github repo](https://github.com/Yaowenjie/travis-github-chrome-extension)

Comment: Nice extension!