# Do GitHub Integrations change GitHub html?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, integration, github-api

I have searched on the internet how **Travis CI** changes some aspects inside the GitHub, see image below:

[GitHub PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJVhB.png)

I checked the html and got something like:

```
<a class="text-green tooltipped tooltipped-e"
       aria-label="Success: The Travis CI build passed"
       href="https://travis-ci.org/brain-labs/brain/builds/181837312">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-check" height="16" 
          version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 12 16" width="12">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 5l-8 8-4-4 1.5-1.5L4 10l6.5-6.5z"></path>
        </svg>
    </a>
```

I might be wrong, but I think that **Travis CI** is including the information together with GitHub output html. Is that right? If yes, does anyone know the exact **GitHub API method/sourcery** to do that?

I am asking that because I would like to change Github's html in order to something like to improve GitHub highlighting. I am already doing that with a [Chrome Extension](https://github.com/github-aux/linguist-unknown), however I am thinking of making a GitHub Integration... I hope someone can help! Thanks!

Comment: Travis isn't changing the HTML - neither can you. Travis is just providing the status (ok, not ok), the link to the build and the status message. It's up to github to show this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change those GitHub links, only your [README, with travis status for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24325309/6309).
See [Travis status image](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/status-images/).

Or you can use another Chrome extension like [Github Travis Stat](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-travis-stat/ekkfhiophiaakmeppcnkblpbbjlnlnmh).

Comment: Thank you so much @VonC, that really helped! I'm on the right way then!